# how to properly define a ManyToMany field in the models.py file

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, models

In my Django app I have the following models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null = False)
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = False)
    command = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = False)
    whenToRun = models.DateTimeField('Run Date', null = False)
    output = models.CharField(max_length = 100000, null = True)

class Host(models.Model):
    jobs = models.ManyToManyField(Job, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False)
    hasRun = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

I added the jobs assignment in the Host class with guidance from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/.  I was able to add Hosts in with no problem (from the admin page) but when I tried to add in a Job I got the following error:

```
Exception at /admin/Minion/job/add
<class 'Minion.models.Host'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'Minion.models.Job'>
```

I tried to add a ManyToManyField assignment to the Job class as well but it told me that the name Host was undefined.  Does anyone know what I can do to make this field function properly?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you previously defined a ForeignKey from Host to Job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `inlines` for `ManyToMany` in `admin.py`

Check [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models) for how to declare inlines

Something like this:

```
class JobInline(admin.TabularInline):
     model = Host.jobs.through
```